# How to decide which ECS tool to use?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I am at a bit of a crossroads here. My goal is to automate creating my ECS architecture and deploying my docker-compose services to ECS Fargate, but there are so many ways to do it!

Hoping to get some insight from the community on picking the right tool for the job.  What are the use cases for each of these? When should I pick one over the other?

Docker ECS integration 
https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/

ecs-cli 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_CLI.html

AWS Copilot 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/AWS_Copilot.html

AWS CLI ecs 
https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecs/index.html

Comment: You left out CloudFormation, AWS CDK, Terraform and Pulumi (I'm probably forgetting a few). The answers to your question are going to be very opinionated I'm afraid. If you're interested in automation I would only look at Copilot from those on your list, but depending on how advanced your needs are I would look at AWS CDK or Terraform.

Comment: The main thing I want to be able to do is to define all my network, database, and storage separately using CloudFormation and then be able to easily deploy to those resources using my docker-compose file. I dont want my network stack to be created automatically.

Comment: Why deploy with docker-compose if you are already using CloudFormation? Why not use that for everything?

Comment: How would I transform a docker-compose into a CloudFormation stack? I don't want to manually describe my ECS tasks, services, etc.

Comment: The problem I find is that I always end up needing to do more advanced things, like mapping in EFS volumes, which just make sense to do in an ECS task definition instead of trying to wedge into your docker-compose file somehow. I maintain a docker-compose file for local development, and ECS task definitions in Terraform for AWS deployments. It's just takes me a few minutes to write an ECS task definition from scratch, so it's not like you are taking on all this extra work by having both.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is how I am breaking it down:

- Docker Compose / ECS integration: use this if you are deep into Docker already are in love with the compose syntax. If you are not already in love with it you should because it's a very simple syntax
- ECS CLI: this is the previous version of the Copilot CLI. ECS CLI had native ECS components/workflows to it + some level of docker compose compatibility. We have since improved the workflows in Copilot and forked compose support into the Docker Compose / ECS integration above. TL/DR: don't use ECS CLI
- Copilot CLI: this is a very easy way to start with containers on AWS ECS. If you don't know much about Docker and you don't need to become an expert in containers Copilot is the right approach. Only drawback (IMO) is that it doesn't really support a proper IaC pattern yet ([example](https://github.com/aws/copilot-cli/issues/1381)).
- AWS CLI (ecs namespace): this is just the CLI manifestation of the 1:1 mapping of the core ECS APIs. This is most likely way too low level for you to extract value (unless you are doing very deep things). For example one Copilot command or a few Docker Compose lines could easily be exploded in dozens of AWS CLI commands.

I'd add CDK to your list: [CDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/home.html) is a representation of AWS constructs (including ECS) that could be represented with standard programming languages. The good thing about CDK is that it could map 1:1 raw API/Cloudformation constructs but it also ships with higher level and more abstracted libraries that allows you to express in a few lines of code content that would require hundreds of lines of CFN.

If you are deep into compose (as it seems from your original message) you may want to have a look at [this approach](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/automated-software-delivery-using-docker-compose-and-amazon-ecs/).

Comment: For me, it came down to `copilot` and `docker-compose`. I wanted to stick with `docker-compose` since it's what we use in our dev environment. The three main realizations that moved me toward `copilot` instead were 1) it's purpose-built for AWS. This is better than trying to get `docker-compose` to do something it wasn't originally designed to do. 2) we'll be using AWS services anyway (Elasticache and Aurora instead of docker containers with MySQL and Redis), so `copilot` is probably more of a natural fit. 3) `copilot pipeline` provides an AWS-friendly approach to CI/CD when we're ready for it